# What is happening here? When I try to run this code, the following error appears

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

```
          -- Creating a procedure to convert DB to XML 
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XML_OUTPUT AS 
        BEGIN
-- Declaring a ref cursor and a variable of type XMLTYPE
DECLARE
  refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  wxmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
-- Prompting the user to input the range of database to be converted
dbms_output.put_line('Input the min value of MESSID');
-- Declaring the ref cursor and pointing it to a select variable
  OPEN refcursor FOR SELECT messname,
                            studentname 
                            FROM studentsmessdata
                            -- Accepting user input for range
                            WHERE messid > &messid; 
  wxmltype:= XMLTYPE(refcursor);
  -- printing the database as XML
  dbms_output.put_line(wxmltype.getClobVal);
END;
  NULL;
END XML_OUTPUT;
```

The following error appears:

> Error: PLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind]
>   Error(9,22): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  Error(12,34): PL/SQL:
>   ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments:
>   [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: When I give a definite value to the parameter messid, say messid > 2, the code is running fine. So, is there something I'm missing in the understanding of what a ref cursor does?

Comment: Which client are you running this in, and what value are you giving for the `messid` substitution parameter? Does it error at compile time or when you call the procedure? I said on an earlier question that you can't prompt the user for input from PL/SQL, so this isn't going to do quite what you think.

Comment: I'm running this on Oracle SQL developer. The datatype of 'messid' is int. So, I'm giving the same input. The error appears at compile time.

Comment: Hey, the code is running fine now.

Comment: You mean the original code in your question, or what was in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error when substitution variables are disabled:

```
set define off

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
...
/

Procedure XML_OUTPUT compiled
Errors: check compiler log

show errors

Errors for PROCEDURE STACKOVERFLOW.XML_OUTPUT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind]
11/22    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/34    PL/SQL: ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

With define set to the default `&` (assuming you're using a client which supports substitution variables; this is in SQL Developer) you are prompted for the `&messid` value at compile time, and that value is then fixed in the procedure definition.

If you want to supply the value at runtime you need to pass it in as a parameter, called something like `p_messid`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XML_OUTPUT(p_messid studentsmessdata.messid%TYPE) AS 
  refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  wxmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Declaring the ref cursor and pointing it to a select variable
  OPEN refcursor FOR SELECT messname,
                            studentname 
                            FROM studentsmessdata
                            -- Accepting user input for range
                            WHERE messid > p_messid; 
  wxmltype:= XMLTYPE(refcursor);
  -- printing the database as XML
  dbms_output.put_line(wxmltype.getClobVal);
END XML_OUTPUT;
/
```

I've removed the redundant nested block to make it a bit shorter. And then you would call it as, for example:

```
set serveroutput on
exec XML_OUTPUT(42);
```